# Invalid object name when executing procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created this procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure CashBook (@startDate DateTime, @endDate DateTime)
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @runningTable TABLE(TransDate DateTime, Debit Money, Credit Money, Balance Money)
   Declare @closingBalance Money, @runningBalance Money, @openingBalance Money
   --Get the opening Balance on the date you want to start at
   SELECT  
       @openingBalance = SUM(coalesce(credit, 0) - coalesce(debit, 0)) 
   FROM
       fms.dbo.Transactions 
   WHERE 
       DataSource IN (4, 3) AND TransDate <  @startDate;

   --Now do the rest
   INSERT INTO @runningTable (TransDate, Credit, Debit, Balance) 
   VALUES (@startDate, NULL, NULL, @openingBalance);

   SELECT @runningBalance = @openingBalance;

   INSERT INTO @runningTable (TransDate, Credit, Debit, Balance) 
      SELECT 
          TransDate, Credit, Debit,
          (coalesce(credit, 0) - coalesce(debit, 0)) AS Balance 
      FROM 
          fms.dbo.Transactions 
      WHERE 
          TransDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate;

  --Calculate the Running Balance
  SELECT  
      @closingBalance = SUM(coalesce(credit, 0) - coalesce(debit, 0)) 
  FROM
      fms.dbo.Transactions 
  WHERE 
      DataSource IN (4, 3) AND TransDate <  @endDate

  --Now do the rest
  INSERT INTO @runningTable (TransDate, Credit, Debit, Balance) 
  VALUES (@endDate, NULL, NULL, @closingBalance)

  --Calculate the Running Balance
  SELECT * FROM @runningTable
END
```

When I execute it in Management Studio, by calling

```
cashbook '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01'
```

I get this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CashBook, Line 8
>   Invalid object name 'Transactions'.

The table `Transactions` exists

**EDIT**

Most commenter are asking if the `sp` is in the same dm `fms`, please see the image below

[image: sp]

Comment: Can you go into the same database that the SP is created in and run `SELECT * FROM fms.dbo.Transactions`

Comment: `fms.dbo.Transactions` is that name correct ?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande i am ruining locally in management studio the database is `fms` the table is `Transactions`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes it works, see my comment above

Comment: can you insert data using single query ? with using this query `INSERT INTO @runningTable (TransDate,Credit,Debit, Balance) VALUES (@startDate, NULL, NULL, @openingBalance);`

Comment: If that select statement returns OK then I'm out of ideas. As you've explained it, there should be no issue.

Comment: @AngusChung see my comments above

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande i dont get you clearly if i can insert data with the query you highlighted

Comment: are you able to insert the data using single query ? means just to crosscheck if you can insert it with simple `insert into transactions values ('','','','') like that`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande yes i can , i have over 1000 rows in the table which i inserted through web app

Comment: @Smith can you debug it using `print`  so what data you are getting from each statement or a whole query .. so that we will know about what is exactly passing and where is errro

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande how do i debug a stored procedure with `print`

Comment: @smith, by fms.dbo.transactions do you really mean to have sp on a database which query `transactions` table from another database? I mean the `sp` and `transactions` are on a same db or on different dbs?

Comment: @RezaRahmati they are on the same db, see the image in the edit

Comment: for debugging https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yet1b7by(VS.80).aspx go through it...

Comment: you can use 

`PRINT '1'
GO

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

PRINT '2'
GO

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'

PRINT '3'
GO`. like wise to get it printed the values of variables what value it is assigned

Comment: @Smith for testing change line 8 to `dbo.Transactions` and tell us the result

Comment: @RezaRahmati I already did that and got the same error

Comment: hi @Smith , does that work for you?

Comment: @AngusChung no it doesn't, but i'm doing serious brainstorming what could be causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the bug

I did thorough check in the database and found that I mistakenly created that cashbook procedure in the master table, so I deleted it

I don't however know why this should interfere with the cashbook in another database

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's cached ,try this way and let us know if it work.

SQL Managenemt→ Edit → IntelliSense → Refresh Local Cache

[image]

Comment: hi Smith , can you execute **Select * from fms.dbo.Transactions**?

Comment: I think that it is because the **permission** of dbo.